# how to to include a file from main domain to subdomain

Tags: php, include, ini-set

want to include a file from main domain to subdomain

**index.php** - on `subdomain.example.com`

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
ini_set("allow_url_include", 1);    
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if($host == 'localhost'){include("../navt.php");}
else{include("https://example.com/navt.php");}
```

on localhost - there is no problem (win 10, xampp, chrome)
on remote server - I'm still getting this:
`include(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0`

Comment: The error indicates to me that your hosting provider overrides the INI setting you used

Comment: Why not just copy paste the file into the subdomain's directory?

Comment: You could also do `else { echo file_get_contents("https://example.com/navt.php"); }` instead

Comment: @nice_dev - because in reality I have 9 subdomains

Comment: @qadenza Still, it's doable

Comment: @nice_dev - duable but the price is very expensive in case you need to change something in `navt.php`

Comment: @qadenza Does this act like an API returning some JSON, or is like a usual file you want to include in your script?

Comment: @nice_dev it's a plain markup inside

Comment: @qadenza Markup as in plain HTML or is it dynamic HTML?

Comment: @nice_dev - plain html - divs, buttons and links

Comment: @qadenza Well, first step is to save them as `.html`

Comment: Also, are you hosting them all(9 subdomains) on a single server? If yes, then of course, you can just have a single directory outside of public_html.

Comment: @qadenza No need to be rude to people who invest time in helping you. Looking at your comment, am I missing something?

Comment: Saving as .html was from a security perspective as it is a bit less vulnerable than .php file as it is an executable code. Also, if all are on same server, import the file from disk, because fetching from a url opens up for phishing attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the `allow_url_include` setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) includes two important details:

- It is changeable at "PHP_INI_SYSTEM" level only, which is [explained elsewhere in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php). It cannot be set at run-time, nor by individual users on a shared server.
- It is deprecated since PHP 7.4.

Both of these are for the same reason: **this setting is extremely dangerous**. It's highly advisable to come up with an alternative solution to your problem, by thinking about *how you deploy your code*. For instance:

- Put the files that need to be shared between the different sub-domains somewhere on disk, and reference those files with a normal (non-URL) `include`.
- Create a shared library that you can deploy to all the sub-domains at once.
- Use the same application for all the sub-domains, with code to detect which one is being displayed.

Comment: thanks a lot. how to make a folder to be `shared`. If I put `navt.php` inside that folder I still need to use `include()` - from main domain url

Comment: @qadenza By "shared" I just mean "use the same ones"; how that looks depends on how you structure your code. The point is that you need to think about _files on the server_, not URLs.